# In needing of a MYSQL Timer

Tags: mysql, database, timer, heidisql

HeidiSQL
Hello Guys im an newbie on the MYSQL side, all my aknloedge on it being pretty basic functions,
i wanted to ask if anyone here has links to good tutorials such as web/videos, to learn how to set up an mysql timer on my database, to delet an especific row every 24h, an tutorial explaining atleast the basic.
on localhost root -> TestDB>Quests and inside the quests  table want it to delete all the rows that contain an especific number id every 24h on the server.

thanks to everyone taht helps me out with tutorials and guides on how to set up the timer!!
and yes ofcourse im already searching for tutorials and more, usign this to help me advance faster!!

still Researching, i wont try it out thill i have the aknleodge to actually do it!

Comment: See `EVENTs` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start with Nathan's blog post at https://sebhastian.com/mysql-timer
It is well written with simple examples.
Good luck.